# How can I improve performance with batches using pyglet?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I have some code that creates a batch using the pyglet library. The whole thing contains about 10 000 quads when fully loaded. Now when I run the script which renders the whole scene (it is a completely static scene), I get 3FPS. The only thing that in the prototype I used for the scene renderer, I would build up the map using some slow and sloppy written python code, which happened to also run at 3FPS for the exact same scene. Since the batches in pyglet are managed using C++, I have this bothering feeling that I am missing something obvious that causes the batch to draw at 3FPS.

This is my scene initialization code:

```
glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluPerspective(60.0, float(width)/height, .1, 10000.)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glClearColor(94.0/255.0, 161.0/255.0, 255.0/255.0, 0.5)
glClearDepth(1.0)
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)  
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

And this is the code that runs each frame to render the scene:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
glTranslatef(0, 0, -1*self.mapZoomLevel)
glRotatef(self.mapPitch/5, 1, 0, 0)
glRotatef(self.mapRotation, 0, 0, 1)
glTranslatef(self.mapX, self.mapY, 0)
self.mapPrimitive.batch.draw()
```

Comment: OS?  OpenGL implementation vendor?  Can you post a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Any problem is most likely to be in your draw() function ... can you post the code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scene is static, it should be easily fixed using a display list. Some vendors optimize display lists by converting them to VBO and glMultiDrawElements() internally so some lousy 10k quads should be no problems. And it's like four lines of code.

Comment: For people finding this: I'd say that going for a VBO directly is best in either case.

Comment: @Bartvbl Actually on some of the old implementations, when the hardware T&L was just emerging, VBOs were at times slower than the simple vertex arrays (I suppose they required more complex pipeline reconfiguration). Counterintuitive but true. On today's hardware VBOs can be of course expected to be superior. But with all the OpenGL 4's bells and whistles, for simple scientific visualisation, nothing beats the simplicity of `glBegin()` / `glEnd()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a shortcut for this if you are using CPython. Pypy has supported pyglet for a while (http://pypy.org/compat.html).
Switching into Pypy, you can get a performance improvement easily, and there is basically no need to change your code. 
Hope helpful to you.